# Laravel default Auth::routes() inside of group prefix

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm attempting to create a prefix with a variable for "companies" to login to the platform. All users are tied to a company so the normal `/login` isn't desired. I'd like to use something like `/acme-company-name/login

I am using the default Laravel auth via: `php artisan make:auth` on a fresh install.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

When I try navigating to `/company-name/login` I see the following error:

`Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {company}/login].`

Looking inside the auto-generated `login.blade.php` I see the function call `route('login')` and this seems to be where everything is breaking. I think I need some way to supply a variable to that function or redefine what the "login" route is in some fashion ? I'd rather not have to replace the call `Auth::routes()` but will certainly do so if that is required to fix this issue.

I should note, i've tried defining the group `'as' => 'company'` and changing `route('company.login')` but then I am told the route `company.login` is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by passing $company variable to the function as well?

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function ($company) {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

And make sure you pass the `company-name` when calling the route as it's a required parameter.

In `login.blade.php` use `{{ url("$company/login") }}` instead of `route('login')`.

Comment: Sadly it looks like I am still missing the {company} parameter with your solution inside of the `login.blade.php`

Comment: Didn't the solution fix the following issue: Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {company}/login]? I'm unable to debug this at the moment, will check on one of instances soon  and let you know.

Comment: No I'm still getting the same error, it's almost as if the `$company` variable isn't processed by `route()`

Comment: In `login.blade.php` can you try `url('company-name/login')` instead of `route('login')`?

Comment: I need the `company-name` to be dynamic based on the prefix variable though

Comment: You can have it as `{{ url("$company/login") }}` and have `$company` dynamic.

Comment: have you tested this ? `$company` is an instance of `Router` not what you are expecting...

Comment: I didn't get to test this, I'm on mobile sadly. `php artisan route:list` shows the dynamic login routes you required with your route implementation though.

Answer (score 0):

`route()` helper has more than one parameter ;)

```
route('login', ['company' => $company])
```

Comment: this sadly doesn't work: Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {company}/login].

Comment: @mkirkpatrick

on my laravel 5.3 it works.
`Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function () {
        Auth::routes();
    });`

and using `$company = 'test-company'` and helper `route('login', ['company' => $company])`

result: `http://somehost.local/test-company/login`

make sure that you use route name (aka alias in older versions) in helper `route` instead of URI. use `php artisan route:list` to see routes

Comment: @mkirkpatrick
seems like you have UrlGenerationException for missing route parameters. make sure that you provide `company` parameter in all `route()` helper calls (in views, etc).

because it works. on almost clear laravel app after `php artisan make:auth`.
https://snag.gy/rNCTbm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

you need to share your prefix in your views and set route as the following:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'],  function ($company) {
   view()->share('company', $company); // share $company in views
   Auth::routes();
});
```

now you have `$company` which is  instance of `Router` and you need access to route prefix value for this you need get current route and get `company` parameter so you should rewrite your `route()` helper function as the following:

```
 {{ route('login',['company'=>$company->getCurrentRoute()->__get('company')]) }}
  // getCurrentRoute Get the currently dispatched route instance
  //__get  Dynamically access route parameters
```

**EDIT:**

you can write custom helper function as the following:

```
  /**
     * Generate the URL to a named route for Company Auth.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  Router  $company 
     * @return string
     */
    function companyRoute($name,$company)
    {
        return app('url')->route($name, ['company'=>$company->getCurrentRoute()->__get('company')] ,true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code that is working fine for me.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{company}'], function () {
    // ensure that auth controllers exists in right place (here it is App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController)
    // in LoginController funtion 
    Auth::routes();

    //or you can try using custom routing like this
    Route::get('{something}', function($company, $something)
    {
        var_dump($company, $something);
    });
});
```

If you define this route at the end of the file then the error that you have mentioned we face.

```
ErrorException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {company}/login]. (View: \resources\views\auth\login.blade.php)
```

Try with defining this route as first route in web.php and check.

Thanks

Comment: moving it to the top doesn't seem to fix anything for me :(

Comment: Can you share the route file with me ?

Comment: Please check if the route that your are accessing is already defined below.
Like domain.com/{company = test}/ then test route is defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking inside the auto-generated login.blade.php I see the function call route('login') and this seems to be where everything is breaking.

Yes. By doing

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{company}'], function () {
    Auth::routes();
});
```

you are making all auth routes take a `company` parameter. So, in your views, instead of `route('login')`, you can do `route('login', ['company' => Request::route('company')])`. (And the same for all auth routes).

Then probably in your `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController` you will need to override the `login` method accordingly:

```
public function login(Request $request, $company)
{
   // you can copy some behaviour from
   // https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L28
}
```

Comment: sadly we get: `UrlGenerationException in UrlGenerationException.php line 17:
Missing required parameters for [Route: login] [URI: {company}/login].`

Comment: @mkirkpatrick that must be some call to `route('login')` without the parameter. Do you want to show the stacktrace for the exception? For instance, in my case the stacktrace shows at #3 the error in the compiled view file.